# Avoid this race condition in C# program

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c#-4.0

I am working on a C# application and facing a strange issue here. I have a .dll which has been built in C++, and I have to call some functions from this .dll from C# app.

Consider this sample code:

```
public partial class MainWindows: Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
ConfigurationFunctions.StartMain(); //Start main is the DLL function in C++ 

int x = ConfigurationFunctions.ReturnIntExp();
StringBuilder sb = ConfigurationOptions.ReturnSomethingExp();
}
}
```

**C++ .cpp file**

```
EXPORT_API int xExp;
EXPORT_API char cExp; 
EXPORT_API StartMain()
{
//Calculate `x` and `y` in this program values here and allocate to variables to be returned from function
xExp = x;
cExp = c;
}
EXPORT_API int ReturnIntExp()
{
return xExp;
}
EXPORT_API char ReturnSomethingExp()
{
return cExp;
}
```

The problem is when I run the `StartMain()` function from the .dll, it calculate some values for for `int` and `char` which have to be allocated to variables (that are actually returned to C# application)

But, after `StartMain()` the C# application should wait till the `StartMain()` function is complete (which in this case takes approx. 3-4 secs and the dll itself fires two/three other processes) and only then proceed further or else, the variables `x` and `sb` in C# application will have empty/meaningless values.

How can I achieve the same in this case?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Function `StartMain` will work until the work is done. When the work is done C# application will gain control of execution and will proceed with calling `ReturnIntExp`. There is no problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a third exported variable `ReturnIsReady()` that returns `true` if the other two methods have meaningful data, and `false` otherwise. Then simply have a loop with a sleep to check that value until it changes.

A better option would be to implement a mutex or similar structure, but spin waiting should be sufficient for a single wait of that length at start up.

Alternatively, why is `StartMain()` returning before filling in the values?

Comment: Can this also be done in StartMain() to return a `finish code int` at the end. So, I could keep checking in the loop for this code until it gives me green signal. Because I can't find out what actually would be    for `xExp` and `cExp` in this case.